# How do I match characters in a string in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a string, ie. yesterday.

I want to match st which is in the middle of yesterday but I don't want to match fast (st at the end) or strong (st in front).

How can I do this with awk?

Here's the code that I tried writing but it doesn't work

```
if ($1 ~/!^st.*st.*!st$/)
```

Comment: What about `fastest` match or not match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use word boundary.

```
awk '!/\<st|st\>/ && /\<.+st.+\>/' file
```

Then it will only print the line if there a no word on the line starting or ending with `st`.  And use `+` instead of `*` to make sure at least one character before and after `st`

If you like to match word with `st` in it but can also be `st` in start end as well, like `fastest`, then this should do:

```
awk '/\<.+st.+\>/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/^st|st$/ && /.*st.*/'  Input_file
```

Comment: i did ```~/.*st.*/ %% !/^st|st$/``` and it works. thanks